# Run a shell script on one rails application from another rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shell, ruby-on-rails-4

I need to run a shell script (e.g. `df`) on a server, say `Client`. The call to this script should be made from another independent rails application, say `Monitor` via REST Api and return the output in response to `Monitor` application.

This shell command should run on all application server instances of `Client`. Though I'm researching on it, it'll be quite helpful if anyone has done this already before.

I need to get following information from `Client` servers to `Monitor` application:

1. Disk space left on each `Client` server instance ,
2. Processes running on each `Client` server instance,
3. Should be able to terminate non-responsive `Client` instance.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A simple command can be executed via:

```
result = `df -h /`
```

But it does not fullfill the requirement *run on all application server instances of Client*. For this you need to call every instance independently.

Another way can be to run your checks from a cron job and let the `Client` call `Monitor`. If a cron is not suited you can create an ActiveJob on every client, collect the data and call `Monitor`

You should also look for ruby libraries providing the data you need.
For instance `sys/filesystem` can provide data about your disk stats.